# smtplib not send mail with same Subject

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib, subject

I use code below to send mails:

```
...

msg = MIMEText(htmlString, 'html', 'utf-8')

msg["Subject"] = "Test Subject"

sm = smtplib.SMTP(SMTPSERVER, port=PORT, timeout=TIMEOUT)

sm.set_debuglevel(1)

# sm.ehlo()
# sm.starttls()
# sm.ehlo()

sm.login(username, password)
sm.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
sm.quit()
```

The question is, every time when I send the mail with same `Subject`, the mail can not send out successfully.

I tried different `Subject` with `Test Subject1` and `Test Subject2` and "`est Subject...` and then the mail sent out successfully immediately.

I have checked the `SMTPSERVER`, there is no filter by `Subject`.

How can I find the reason and solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try another SMTP server?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is stored in the `msg.as_string()` variable and empty the value of the variables before each iteration